# Add parent menu item in sub-menu in custom nav_walker

Tags: php, functions, menus, walker

Currently I'm working on a project where we need to append the parent title as first item in the submenu for a mobile menu.

What I try to achieve is this:

```
 <ul class="menu">
   <li>
     <a href="linktomenu">Level 0 item</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
       <li><a href="linktoparent">Show All Level 0 item </a></li>
       <li><a href="#0">Back to parent</a></li>
       <li><a href="linktomenu">Level 1 item</a></li>
       <li><a href="linktomenu">Level 1 item</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

This is the code I currently have

```
 <?php

class mobilenav_walker_nav_menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

  private $color_idx = 0;

  // add classes to ul sub-menus
  function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array()) {
    // depth dependent classes
    $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
    $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
    $classes = array(
                'sidebar-menu',
                ( $display_depth % 2  ? 'menu-odd' : 'menu-even' ),
                ( $display_depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu' : '' ),
                'level-' . $display_depth
              );
    $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

    $back_btn = '';

    if($display_depth > 0){
      $parent_label = '<li class="go-back"><a href="#0"><span class="parent_label"></span><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></li>';

      $back_btn = '<li class="see-all"><a class="hit-area" href="#">Back</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></li>';
    }

    // build html
    $incri = $this->color_idx-1;
    $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="menu__level" data-menu="submenu-'.$incri.'">' .$parent_label.$back_btn. "\n";
  }

  // add main/sub classes to li's and links
  function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = Array(), $id = 0 ) {

    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent

    // depth dependent classes
    $depth_classes = array(
        'sidebar-item',
        ( $depth == 0 ? 'li0' : '' ),
        ( $depth == 1 ? 'li1' : '' ),
        ( $depth == 2 ? 'li2' : '' ),
        ( $depth == 3 ? 'li3' : '' ),
        ( $depth % 2 ? 'menu-item-odd' : 'menu-item-even' ),
        'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
    );

    if(in_array('menu-item-has-children',$item->classes)){
      $has_children = 'data-has-children="1"';
      $has_children_var = 1;
      $depth_classes[] = 'has-children';
    } else{
      $has_children_var = 0;
      $depth_classes[] = 'no-children';
    }

    $li_attributes = 'data-level="'.$depth.'" data-title="'.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).'" '.$has_children;

    $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );

    // passed classes
    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

    // build html
    $output .= $indent . '<li class="menu__item"'.$li_attributes.'>';

    // link attributes
    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    if($has_children_var == 1){
      $attributes .= ' data-submenu="submenu-'.$this->color_idx.'"';
    }
    $attributes .= ' class="menu__link"';

    $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
      $args->before,
      $attributes,
      $args->link_before,
      apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
      ($has_children_var == 1 ? $args->link_after : ''),
      $args->after
    );

    // build html
    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );

    if($has_children_var == 1){
      $this->color_idx++;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the current output I have

```
  <ul id="menu-hoofdnavigatie" class="sidebar-menu level-0">
    <li class="menu__item" data-level="0" data-title="Menu Item Level 0" data-has-children="1"><a data-submenu="submenu-0" class="menu__link">Menu Item Level 0</a>
      <ul class="menu__level" data-menu="submenu-0">
        <li class="go-back"><a href="#0"><span class="parent_label"></span><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></li>
        <li class="see-all"><a class="hit-area" href="#">Back</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></li>
        <li class="menu__item" data-level="1" data-title="Menu Item 1 Level 1"><a class="menu__link">Menu Item 1 Level 1</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item" data-level="1" data-title="Menu Item 2 Level 1"><a class="menu__link">Menu Item 2 Level 1</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item" data-level="1" data-title="Menu Item 3 Level 1"><a class="menu__link">Menu Item 3 Level 1</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item" data-level="1" data-title="Menu Item 4 Level 1"><a class="menu__link">Menu Item 4 Level 1</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item" data-level="1" data-title="Menu Item 5 Level 1"><a class="menu__link">Menu Item 5 Level 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I'm quite new to the wordpress navwalker, can you help me on this one? I've searched the entire internet, but could not find a solution for my problem so far.

Comment: can you post the markup of your current result?

Comment: I've updated my question with the markup of the current result

Comment: sp you already have the `parent_label` as first item in the submenu. you now miss the output of the real name of the parent now?

Comment: Yes, I miss the output of the real name and the URL ;-)

Answer (score 0):

*So you need to real name and URL of the parent in the submenu.*

You have **no info about a post item** in your `function start_lvl()`.

But in `function start_el()` **you have the items** and could query for it's parent.

This needs some **refactoring** with putting lines like the `if($display_depth > 0){` condition from `start_lvl` function into your `start_el` function. Then writing **a proper WP query** to get the Info's of the parent item you need in the submenu.

#### To point a bit more specific:

In `start_el` function you have the var `$item` which should contain the ID of the post it represents. Should be `$itemId = $item->Id`. 
If so you should get the parent with `$parentId = wp_get_post_parent_id( $itemId );` and further more you can fetch infos from the parent with the parent ID with some other WP functions.

*Hope that helps to find your way..*

Comment: Ok, sounds plausible. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Wouter updated my post to point you in a more specific direction.

Comment: thanks, keep on trying for two hours now, but I'm not able to get the job done :-(